# How to enforce release of resources?

Tags: java, autocloseable

I have a class called Parameter that wraps different values including `java.sql.Clob`

With JDBC4 specification, we have a `free()` method that can be called to free resources allocated to `Clob` object. I am thinking of making `Parameter` class an `AutoClosable` and call `free()` method inside `close()`

This works out great but i also want something to enforce or at least hint others that `Parameter` is an instance of `AutoClosable`

Other than documentation is there a way to achieve this? Basically i am looking for something extra that one can do in this situation.

Comment: Who shall give this hint to programmer using `Parameter`? The IDE? The compiler?

Comment: [AutoCloseable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) is an interface. What more "hint" do you want other than implement it?

Comment: @Lutz Horn I was thinking from IDE point of view. I know my question is absurd but i don't have better way to put it. :)

Comment: Do you want to hint or to enforce? You can't prevent a programmer using a  `Parameter` in a normal `try`/`catch`(/`finally`)  way. There is no way to *forcing* the use of TWR.

Comment: The only way to "enforce" it is to not give up control of the process. That is, your code will open and close the `Parameter` and will accept a callback it can invoke to do everything in between.

Comment: @biziclop Great idea. Though i am not sure how i will achieve that with my existing structure.

Comment: I remember that at least some compilers give warning when AutoClosable is not closed, at least in somem situations.

Answer (score 1):

Usual way to do this is implement an `ObjectPool` with a configurable timeout. Start counting when object taken from `ObjectPool` and check if it's returned to the pool at the end of timeout. If the `Object` is not returned to the pool throw an exception or forcibly release the resources that `Object` is keeping. This way you will force programmer to call `close()` method or detect leaks.

Most of Database Connection Pooling libraries has this feature. Check [JDBCConnectionPool - InactiveConnectionTimeoutSeconds](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/ConsoleHelp/domain_jdbcconnectionpool_config_connections.html#InactiveConnectionTimeoutSeconds) and [Apache Commons Pool - AbandonedConfig](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/apidocs/org/apache/commons/pool2/impl/AbandonedConfig.html)